# How to get the neural net weights from an h2o deeplearning object

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I have an h2o  deep learning object created using h20.deeplearning. How do I extract the neural net wieghts from this object?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use h2o.weights to extract the neural net weigths. You can reference our documentation here:
http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-simons/7/docs-website/h2o-r/h2o_package.pdf

and get an example of h2o.weights's usage here:
https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/tests/testdir_algos/deeplearning/runit_deeplearning_weights_and_biases.R

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the similar function to h2o.weights for Python?